# React app can't get data from ExpressJS API

Tags: reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I've run into issue where I can't get confirmation that user is authenticated from ExpressJS backend. I am using PassportJS with Google OAuth2.

When I try to access my API endpoint through browser, it returns the data I need. Why is this so? Is there a problem with cors and backend or with my request?

This is the error I get after a while on the same page: `GET http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login/success net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Here is my request:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await axios
                .get(`${API_URL}/auth/login/success`, {
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                    },
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response === 200) {
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log("200");
                        return response.json();
                    }
                    throw new Error("Failed to authenticate the user.");
                })
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    userHasAuthenticated(true);
                    setUser(responseJson.user);
                    console.log("responseJson");
                    setLoading(false);
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [loading]);
```

I dont't get any outputs to the console.

Here is my route on the backend:

```
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log("/login/success");
    if (req.user) {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "User has successfully authenticated.",
            user: req.user,
            cookies: req.cookies,
        });
    }
});
```

When I try to access this route on my browser, I see the response and it prints it out in the console. But when I visit the frontend page from where the request is sent, nodejs console prints out undefined.

Comment: so `user` is not present on `req` cause you are not passing it from front-end?

Comment: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0 I used this tutorial, but I can't see the part where they pass it from front-end. How should I do it?